# VBA assign numbered variables in loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I'm attempting to create numbered variables (ie., suminterest_X where "X" goes from 1 to 20 and produces 20 different variables, one for each process in the loop).

My code is currently:

Let `suminterest_& CStr(i) = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Worksheets("Bond_" & CStr(i)).Cells(8, 5), Worksheets("Bond_" & CStr(i)).Cells(7 + wam1, 5)))`

However, when writing this line I get a syntax error.

The syntax works when writing the line:

```
Worksheets("Bond_" & CStr(i)).Cells(7 + j, 3) = j
```

Used in an earlier piece of code.

Can anyone help me with how to code this correctly?

EDIT:

Here's my whole loop:

`create the variables and tables
For i = 1 To 20
    'assingment of variables
    Let wac1 = Cells(3 + i, 2)
    Let wam1 = Cells(3 + i, 3)
    Let prince1 = Cells(3 + i, 4)
    Let annualdef1 = Cells(3 + i, 5)
    Let annualprepay1 = Cells(3 + i, 6)
    Let loss1 = Cells(3 + i, 7)`

```
'creation of tables
For j = 1 To wam1
    Worksheets("Bond_" & CStr(i)).Cells(7 + j, 3) = j
    Worksheets("Bond_" & CStr(i)).Cells(7 + j, 4) = prince1
    Worksheets("Bond_" & CStr(i)).Cells(7 + j, 5) = ipayment(prince1, wac1)
    Worksheets("Bond_" & CStr(i)).Cells(7 + j, 7) = preprince(prince1, annualprepay1, j, wam1)
    Worksheets("Bond_" & CStr(i)).Cells(7 + j, 8) = defprince(prince1, annualdef1)
    Worksheets("Bond_" & CStr(i)).Cells(7 + j, 6) = schedpay(prince1, Worksheets("Bond_" & CStr(i)).Cells(7 + j, 8), j, wam1)
    Worksheets("Bond_" & CStr(i)).Cells(7 + j, 9) = recovprince(Worksheets("Bond_" & CStr(i)).Cells(7 + j, 8), loss1)
    Worksheets("Bond_" & CStr(i)).Cells(7 + j, 10) = totprincepaid(Worksheets("Bond_" & CStr(i)).Cells(7 + j, 6), Worksheets("Bond_" & CStr(i)).Cells(7 + j, 7), Worksheets("Bond_" & CStr(i)).Cells(7 + j, 8), recov1(loss1))
    Worksheets("Bond_" & CStr(i)).Cells(7 + j, 11) = balance1(Worksheets("Bond_" & CStr(i)).Cells(7 + j, 4), Worksheets("Bond_" & CStr(i)).Cells(7 + j, 6), Worksheets("Bond_" & CStr(i)).Cells(7 + j, 7), Worksheets("Bond_" & CStr(i)).Cells(7 + j, 8))
    prince1 = Worksheets("Bond_" & CStr(i)).Cells(7 + j, 11)
Next j
    suminterest = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Worksheets("Bond_" & CStr(i)).Cells(8, 5), Worksheets("Bond_" & CStr(i)).Cells(7 + wam1, 5)))
```

`Next i
Range("M1") = suminterest`

I want to be able to store each of the 20 suminterest as their own variables and type range("M1") = suminterest_X to get the corresponding variable.

Comment: "I'm attempting to create numbered variables" - why do you need that?

Comment: I have a loop creating 20 tabs, each with a different table. I want to be able to sum a column in each of the 20 tabs and save them as a variable "suminterest_X" with "suminterest_1" corresponding to the sum of a column in table 1, and so on.

Comment: In general, a dictionary or some primitive OOP would be quite ok for your needs.

Comment: Have you tried: Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Worksheets("Bond_" & CStr(i)).Range("E8:E" & 7 + wam1))

Comment: I edited my question, hopefully it will put it in more context.

Answer (score 1):

You want to store your numbers in an array (*of variables*).
Using an array you can return `suminterest(i)` rather than `suminterest_& CStr(i)`

```
Public Sub Test()

    Dim SumInterest(1 To 20) As Double
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 20
        SumInterest(i) = i * 2
    Next i

    Dim ReturnFrom As Long

    ReturnFrom = InputBox("Enter number between 1 and 20.")

    MsgBox "The value at position " & ReturnFrom & " is:  " & SumInterest(ReturnFrom)

End Sub
```

- By default an array will start at 0, so `Dim SumInterest(20)` will
  give you 21 values (0 - 20).
- You can specify the bounds of an array with `Dim SumInterest(1 To 20)`
- You can resize an array using `REDIM`.
- You can find the lower bound of an array using `LBOUND(SumInterest)` (returns 1 in my example).
- You can find the upper bound of an array using `UBOUND(SumInterest)`
- Then there's multi-dimension arrays, collections, dictionaries.....

Answer (score 0):

In `Worksheets("Bond_" & CStr(i)).Cells(7 + j, 3) = j` you are assiging a string to `"Bond_"`, not a variable.

---

If you want to have some `String` values in array, assigned through a loop, like this:

[image]

Then you can do it via the following code:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim myArr   As Variant
    Dim cnt     As Long

    ReDim myArr(5)
    For cnt = 0 To 5
        myArr(cnt) = "suminterest_" & cnt
    Next

End Sub
```